# Amazon S3 & CloudFront high costs

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We're uploading and serving/streaming media (pics,videos) using amazon s3 for storage combined with cloudfront for serving media. The site is used slightly but the Amazon costs come to 3000 $ per month and from the report 90% of the costs originate from the S3 service .

Heard that cloud can be expensive if you don't code the right way ..now my questions :
What is the right way ? and where should I pay more attention, to the way I upload files or to the way I serve them?

Has anyone else had to deal with unexpected high costs , if yes what was the cause?

Comment: Have you enabled logging for your buckets? You can use http://www.s3stat.com/ service for monitoring.

Comment: I had enabled it 4 a while and it generated a big bunch of files from which I couldn't make much sense . 
Do you have some pointers about what should I look for , more specifically?

Comment: What I've noticed is that the action that has the biggest Usage Values are the ListBucket / Data-Transfer-Out-Bytes

Comment: Can the problem be that I have one bucket with 10.000 items in it , is the best practice to create one bucket for every item , because otherwise it will list all the bucket every time you get one object from it ?(sounds weird tho')

Comment: 1. Enable logs back and setup S3Stat - it will take care of them. In result you are able to see what is's happening there...
2. Why do you need to list your bucket? Don't you know your keys?

Comment: I know my keys, I don't list them (I think).. It was just a wild  guess on what might generate the costs. 
I have 2 situations : 

1)where I know the name of the object I want and I build the url to it 

2)where I know the name of the 'folder' (in a bucket), Where I have 2 objects max ,which names I don't know and I do a listing on the folder with the only  2 obj -- Do you think this listing on a folder actually execute on the whole bucket ? (as I red that folders in cloud aren't actually folders )

Comment: GET Bucket Operation returns up to 1000 (by default) of the objects. If response is truncated, 'IsTruncated' flag is set to true.  To return the additional keys you should use 'marker' value which specifies the key to start with when listing objects.

Answer (score 2):

We have almost similar model. We stream (rtmp ) from S3 and cloudfront. We do have 1000s of files and decent load, but our monthly bill for s3 is around 50$ ( negligible as compared to your figure). Firstly , you should complain about your charges to the technical support of AWS. They always give you a good response and also suggest better ways to utilize resources. Secondly , I think if you do live streaming, where you divide the file into chucks and stream them one by one, instead of streaming or downloading the whole file, it might be effective , in terms of i/o where users are not watching the whole video, but just the part of it. Also, you can try to utilize caching eat application level.

Answer (score 2):

Another opportunity to get better picture on what's going on in your buckets: [Qloudstat](https://qloudstat.com/welcome)